# UploadiFive file delete uploaded file from server?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

i got uploadifive uploader and i have to remove file from server when user clicks X button. Any ideas? :) Thanks!

http://prntscr.com/25qdla screenshot of uploaded file`s content.

current code:

```
                $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
                    'formData'     : {
                        'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                        'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
                    },    
                    'fileSizeLimit' : '500MB',  
                    'itemTemplate' : '<p class="files uploadifive-queue-item"><i onclick="removeFile()" class="ico close" style="cursor: pointer;" title="<?=$this->lang->line('modadd_4_filespan_delete');?>"></i><span class="filename"></span><span class="fileinfo"></span></p>',
                    'queueID'      : 'ify_queue',
                    'uploadScript' : 'uploaders/wv_ify',
                    'buttonText'   : '<a style="margin-top: -7px; margin-left: -16px; height: 38px; width: 132%; cursor: pointer;"><?=$this->lang->line('modadd_4_files_button_text');?></a>',
                    'method'   : 'post',
                    'fileTypeExts' : '*.rar;*.zip;*.7z;*.scs;',  
                    'onUpload' :function(file) {
                        $("#msg_error_display, #msg_success_display").hide();
                        $("#msg_error_display").fadeIn(100, function(){
                            $(this).find('span').html("<?=$this->lang->line('modadd_4_uploading_files');?>");
                        });
                        checker = 0;
                    },
                    'onQueueComplete':function(file, data) {
                        $("#msg_error_display, #msg_success_display").hide();
                        if(checker == 0){
                            $("#msg_success_display").fadeIn(100, function(){
                                $(this).find('span').html("<?=$this->lang->line('modadd_4_uploading_files_end');?>")
                            });
                        } else if(checker == 1){
                            $("#msg_error_display").fadeIn(100, function(){
                                $(this).find('span').html("<?=$this->lang->line('modadd_4_uploading_files_stop');?>")
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    'onError' : function(errorType) {
                        $("#msg_error_display, #msg_success_display").hide();
                        checker = 1;
                    },
                    'onProgress' : function() {
                        console.log(e.bytesloaded);
                    },                      
                    'onUploadComplete' : function() {
                        console.log($('.uploadifive-queue-item').find(".fileinfo").html(""));
                        $("#no_files_uploaded").hide();
                        uploaded_files += 1;
                        all_uploaded_files += 1;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem,
We have 2 properties uploadScript and checkScript, I think could have a propertie like removeScript which we implement a script to delete the file.

But how there isn`t,

We can implement onCancel event with some ajax to call this script, you can make a code like this (add this onCancel on your code):

```
$('#file_upload').uploadifive({
   // Other Atributes and Methods

   // onCancel event implement with ajax to remove files
   // the argument "file" has many attributes 
   // how name, which you use to delete file on server
   // remeber argument file is an json object
   onCancel : function(file) {
       $.post('ajax-method-with-delete.php',file)
   } 
});
```